# PSCP not copying all the files from Linux Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, scp

I am trying to copy a folder/directory from Ubuntu Server to Windows using PSCP.

I am using following command to copy:
`pscp.exe -r -pw pass user@10.10.10.11:/u02/mycode/code .`

Above command does not copy complete folder from above server.

Actual size of folder on Ubuntu machine is approx 767MB. But when I copy the folder on Windows it shows folder size approx 270MB.

**I have not used compression option in command**

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're copying stuff from a case sensitive to case insensitive filesystem a possible cause is files with names that differ only in case (Fred and Fred for example).

If it's not that try using the `-v` option with `pscp` to get more information on what is being copied. Try to find the minimum set of files which demonstrates the problem.

If you explicitly copy the files which are missing on destination does that work?

Answer (score 0):

Right now we can only guess as to what the problem is, you will need to do more work to help us help you. My current guess though is [cosmic rays](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ballard/bofh/bofhserver.pl).

Please determine which files have not been copied and examine them for reasons why they have not been copied. Once you know which files haven't copied, you can check things like the permissions or ownerships on the files and their directories etc ...

Comment: @lain, Thanks for suggestion.  I have done the analysis. Always same numbers of files and same files are not copied. Also no error message is shown on console. If you know any way to debug this issue pl let me know. I will try my best to find the root cause.

Comment: @Sachin Iain told you the way to debug - check permissions or ownership on the files/directories which aren't getting copied.